# How do I calculate the difference

Tags: sql

I have data in two columns. I need to write a query that only shows the customers that have gone over their credit limit and by how much:

```
customer balance         credit limit  
418.75                   500
10.75                    200
200.1                    100
```

Comment: James, what have you tried so far? What do your tables look like? Any particular reason this is being done in SQL rather than in higher-level language code?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I assume you want to write an SQL query that selects based on the comparison of two columns? Also, is this homework?

Comment: Careful: the relational operator [difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_difference#Relative_complement) has a completely different meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this doesn't take customer information into account since you didn't mention any customer tables, but this should get you the customer balance and overage:

```
SELECT customer_balance, credit_limit, customer_balance - credit_limit as overage
FROM your_table
WHERE customer_balance > credit_limit
```

It's pretty straight-forward; you select customers with a balance over their limit, and just select the difference as a third column.